# Win32: Small Icon doesn't show

Tags: c, winapi, loadimage

[image: EDIT]I'm learning Win32 programming
I used LoadImage(...) to set the small icon for the window but it doesn't seem to be working and I cannot pinpoint the problem

```
void AddIcons(HWND hw)
{
    HICON hi = LoadImage(NULL, "ICON.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 16, 16, LR_LOADFROMFILE);

    printf("Icon initialized\n");

    if(hi)
    {
        printf("%x\n", hi);
        SendMessage(hw, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, (LPARAM)hi);
    }

}
```

And the windows procedure:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND handle, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_SETICON: printf("REQUEST RECEIVED\n");
    }
.
.  // AddIcons() is called here
.  // DefWindowProc() handles the message at the end
}
```

I get all three print statements including `REQUEST RECEIVED`.

However, the icon is still the default. Where is the problem occuring?

I am aware that I can use keep a resource file and use LoadIcon(..) but I am more comfortable doing everything programatically. Which begs a second question:

Can everything that can be done using resource(.rc) files be done programmatically?
If so, is one method inherently better than the other?

Comment: `WM_SETICON` accept only icon format, when `LoadImage` with `IMAGE_BITMAP` - create bitmap only. so and must be error

Comment: I have tried this with a '.ico' file and 'IMAGE_ICON'  aswell. It doesnt work even then

Comment: What you describe works fine here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It doesn't unfortunately

Comment: @VTT Im letting the default handle it

Comment: Actually you can not use `.bmp` files as icons, only `.ico` files are supported.

Comment: Sure it does. That message works fine. You are doing something wrong. Since you won't provide a MCVE and you even showed code that you know cannot work, but described that you've also, apparently, done it the right way, it's hard to help.

Comment: .ico file is giving an error code 0 when i call GetLastError() which is ERROR_SUCCESS. I dont understand..

Comment: `ERROR_SUCCESS` means that everything works fine.

Comment: but LoadImage() returns null so everything is not fine...

Comment: I guess you are already running code that is considerably different than what is present in you question. You should include new code as well.

Comment: `HICON hi = (HICON)LoadImage(NULL, "ICON.ico", IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, LR_LOADFROMFILE);` is the only change. ICON.ico is present in the project file.

Comment: Don't ask the question in comments. Use an edit to provide a [mcve].

Comment: It should be present in the application working directory, otherwise application won't be able to find it.

Comment: I have added an image in the question

Comment: Don't ever use relative paths. If you need a file name relative to your executable image, construct a fully qualified path name from the executable image's path.